# Conditions in While loops

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
 int sum = 0, value = 0;
 // read until end-of-file, calculating a running total of all values read
 while (std::cin >> value)
 sum += value; // equivalent to sum = sum + value
 std::cout << "Sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

I studied while loop is used to loop over a given code when a condition is met , but I dont see a condition here ... the only parameter I see is cin asking for value but I dont think thats a condition

Comment: The term **condition** can sometimes be misleading, it is more precisely a boolean expression  or practically any expression— any boolean or non-boolean expression that evaluates to true or false(truthy and falsey values) can be the loop guard. Some languages such as Java strictly demand that it be a boolean value which is not the case with C++ where any expression is implicitly coerced to be true or false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `std::cin >> value` returns a value (a reference to the stream `std::cin`). The value is implicitly casted to `true` if the read was successful and to `false` if the read failed. The function [`std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) is used for the implicit cast.

I think cppreference can describe it better than me:

> `std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::operator bool`
>
> C++ Input/output library std::basic_ios
>
> `operator void*() const;` (1) (until C++11)
>
> `explicit operator bool() const;` (2) (since C++11)
>
> Checks whether the stream has no errors.
>
> 1. Returns a null pointer if `fail()` returns `true`, otherwise returns a non-null pointer. This pointer is implicitly convertible to `bool` and may be used in boolean contexts.
> 2. Returns `true` if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O operations. Specifically, returns `!fail()`.
>
> This operator makes it possible to use streams and functions that return references to streams as loop conditions, resulting in the idiomatic C++ input loops such as `while(stream >> value) {...}` or `while(getline(stream, string)){...}`. Such loops execute the loop's body only if the input operation succeeded.